# PyQt5-python3.5.2 Can't show image

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I've been working through this since yesterday. 
So, the problem is the 'Example_Pix' part. It's the same code coded by other programmer, but it doesn't work: no image is shown. Can someone tell me what the problem is?

```
#Import necessary modules

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def hex_color(self, color): #Changes hex color to Q color
        r = int(color[0:2], 16)
        g = int(color[0:2], 16)
        b = int(color[0:2], 16)
        return QColor(r, g, b)

    def Center(self):  #Moves window to center
        Retrieve_Geometry = self.frameGeometry()
        Center_Screen = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        Retrieve_Geometry.moveCenter(Center_Screen)
        self.move(Retrieve_Geometry.topLeft())

    def Example_Pix(self):
        label = QLabel()
        pixmap = QPixmap('icon2.png')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)


    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("bear GUI")
        self.setGeometry(850, 850, 850, 850)
        self.Center()
        self.Example_Pix()
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

The label isn't being added to `MainWindow` anywhere. The standard way to do this is to place it in a [layout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html). You need to add something like this to your code

```
# Create a layout and add your label to it
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(label)

# Create a central widget for QMainWindow and assign the layout
widget = QWidget()
widget.setLayout(layout)
self.setCentralWidget(widget)
```

Comment: Wow it did it. It seems that I constantly missed the create central widget part. Thank you.